# Can a triangle have 3 irrational angles that are not rational multiples of eachother

Tags: arithmetic, triangles, irrational-numbers, ratio

Consider a triangle where the three angles must sum to a fixed total. I don't care if they sum to $\pi, \frac{\pi}{2}, 360, 180, 1$ or any other number.

If every angle is irrational and they add up to the total 'degrees' in a triangle, is it possible that the ratios of the angles are also irrational?

Put another way: are there $3$ irrational numbers that sum to $1$, such that the ratios of any pair of these numbers is also irrational?

Comment: Have you tried any examples?

Comment: The closest I got was an example using logarithms (in base 10). For instance, log(2) + log(4) + log(125) = 3. However, I wasn't sure how to verify that the ratios of these numbers (or similar triplets) is irrational.

Comment: Another way I considered was 3 infinite series following these patterns:                        .03003000300003...                                           .10210212012120...                                          .20120121021210...                                        These should sum to .33333... in decimal notation (i.e. 1/3), but again I wasn't sure how to check if the ratios were also irrational.

Comment: $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 + (4 - \sqrt  2 - \sqrt 3) = 4$.

Comment: I guess you can construct a solution that's true by definition.. I must be overthinking things. Thank you.

Comment: "Consider a triangle where the three angles must sum to a fixed total. I don't care if they sum to $\pi, \pi^2, 360, 180$ or 1."  Huh???  The angles in a triangle sum to 1?  What universe is that?

Answer (score 5):

Consider the irrational numbers $a,b,c$.

Let $a = \frac{5-\sqrt{2}}{9}, b= \frac{4-\sqrt{2}}{9}, c = \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{9}$

Then $a+b+c = 1$

$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{5-\sqrt{2}}{4-\sqrt{2}} = \frac{18+\sqrt{2}}{14}$$

$$\frac{a}{c} = \frac{ 5-\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{2}} = \frac{-2+5\sqrt{2}}{4}$$

$$\frac{b}{c} = \frac{4-\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{2}} = \frac{-1+2\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Which are all irrational as required.

Answer (score 2):

Take $A=\sqrt2, B=\sqrt3,C=\sqrt5$.  Clearly for any real $k>0$, the three numbers $kA, kB,kC$ are not rational multiples of each other. Choose $k$ such that $kA+kB+kC=\pi$. Now a triangle whose angles (in radians) are $kA, kB, kC$ exists and provide a solution to the question.

EDIT (prompted by the  comment of dxiv pointing out a lacuna).

As $\pi$ is transcendental, for our choice of $k$, we will have  $kA, kB,kC$ irrational.

Comment: You should add that $kA,kB,kC$ are all irrational in this case.